# How to get x y coordinates of an image in php

Tags: php, image

How to get x y coordinates of an image in PHP?

I have an image

`$image = images/abc.png;`

how to get the coordinates of the image using PHP.

Comment: Do you mean the width and height? coordinates would always be 0,0 in php :p

Comment: Question doesn't show what exactly do you need. Where are you applying/needing this, technically??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean width and height you would do:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("img.jpg");
$w = imagesx($img);
$h = imagesy($img);
```

EDIT: if you want to know where an image is on the screen that is not a job for PHP but for a client-side language, like JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

```
<?Php
$foo_x=$_POST['foo_x'];
$foo_y=$_POST['foo_y'];
echo "X=$foo_x, Y=$foo_y ";
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="image" alt="Finding coordinates of an image" src="images.jpeg" 
name="foo" style="cursor:crosshair;" />
</form>
```

i hope this answers your query

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about image dimensions, `getimagesize()` function is for you!